# Can we make an XP synonym the canonical tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I recently added [extreme-programming](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extreme-programming) as a synonym for [xp](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xp). However, it seems that it should really be the other way around, e.g. that [extreme-programming](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extreme-programming) is the canonical name to which the abbreviation [xp](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xp) should point.

However, the system doesn't allow me to do this. Perhaps one needs a cape and super-powers—or at least diamond-moderator privileges—to do this. If that's the case, I'd like the request that someone with the appropriate super-hero costume make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and used the power of the mystical diamond to swap the synonym with the canonical name. Oddly, there are 76 questions tagged "xp" and only one tagged "extreme programming", but synonyms allow for the flexibility of users choosing the tag they prefer.

Up, up, and away to do more good deeds! :)